# Tomar los datos del textform y al darle al botón tomarlos, y con la Api buscar una coincidencia, y pintar los datos según esa coincidencia

Tags: api, flutter

Trato de enviar el dato del textformfield a la api y según el api encuentre una coincidencia entre sus datos quiero recibirlos y pintarlos en otra ventana. Ya con *dio* logré hacer que en otra ventana me pinte los datos de manera get, específicamente los que quiero, pero requiero esa funcionalidad.
Ya he intentado ver muchos tutoriales, pero ya no encuentro la manera de darle solución lógica.

```
// ignore: unused_import
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:prueba/infraestructure/data.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

// second_screen.dart

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> postData(String data) async {
    try {
      final response = await Dio().post(
        'https://black-diamond.com.co/API/public/api/showorders?key=EXaR0JoKIirohPwbRPIHc3s73Oygi0XV',
        data: {'code': data}, // Aquí se envía el dato ingresado
        

      );
      setState(() {
        
        // Procesa la respuesta POST aquí si es necesario
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
        print(data);

      print('Error en la solicitud POST: $e');
      // Manejar el error de solicitud aquí si es necesario
    }
  }

  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String dataToSend = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Coloca tu imagen aquí
            Image.asset(
              'assets/Logo.png', // Ruta de tu imagen
              width: 400, // Ancho de la imagen
              height: 400, // Alto de la imagen
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/fondo_login.png'), // Ruta de tu imagen de fondo
            fit: BoxFit.cover, // Ajusta la imagen para cubrir todo el Container
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Campo de entrada
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: textEditingController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Ingrese el Codigo de la Factura',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                    isDense: true,
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor:
                        Colors.white, // Establece el color de fondo en blanco
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Botón
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  dataToSend = textEditingController.text;
                  postData(dataToSend);

                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const SecondScreen(),
                  ));
                  // Lógica a ejecutar cuando se presione el botón
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 147, 22),
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 16),
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20), // Ajusta el tamaño del texto del botón
                ),
                child: const Text('Enviar'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

segunda vista codigo get para pintar datos en APi, usando Dio :

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SecondScreenState createState() => SecondScreenState();
}

class SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  DataUs? data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    try {
      final response = await Dio().get(
          'https://black-diamond.com.co/API/public/api/orders?key=EXaR0JoKIirohPwbRPIHc3s73Oygi0XV');
      setState(() {
        data = DataUs.fromJson(response.data);

        setState(() {});
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Error en la solicitud GET: $e');
      // Manejar el error de solicitud aquí si es necesario
    }
  }

//segunda pantalla
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text('Estado de Envio'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/fondo_login.png'), // Reemplaza con la ruta de tu imagen
            fit: BoxFit.cover, // Para que la imagen se ajuste al contenedor
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "ID: ${data?.data[0].id.toString() ?? 'No disponible.'}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Codigo de Compra: ${data?.data[0].code.toString() ?? 'No disponible'}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, // Cambia el color del textor
                    fontSize: 20.0, // Cambia el tamaño del texto
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Objetos Totales Comprados: ${data?.data[0].total.toString() ?? 'No disponible'}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, // Cambia el color del textor
                    fontSize: 20.0, // Cambia el tamaño del texto
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Metodo de Pago : ${data?.data[0].paramPaymethod.toString() ?? 'No disponible'}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, // Cambia el color del textor
                    fontSize: 20.0, // Cambia el tamaño del texto
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Estado de Factura: ${data?.data[0].paramStatus.toString() ?? 'No disponible'}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, // Cambia el color del textor
                    fontSize: 20.0, // Cambia el tamaño del texto
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Estado de Compra: ${data?.data[0].paramState.toString() ?? 'No disponible'}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, // Cambia el color del textor
                    fontSize: 20.0, // Cambia el tamaño del texto
                  ),
                ),
                // Puedes seguir agregando más Text con sus respectivos estilos
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```